# SHA-512 on Oracle

Tags: oracle, hash, cryptography, oracle12c, sha512

I want to encrypt some data with SHA-512 on Oracle 12.

For example, I would like to encrypt this string:

```
230049008251111
```

to this:

`DA9AA3ACDE64DB3297FF75FDE407DAF3DB7EFF0CDF987C6C16BAF28242997046997EBF5A2F6C4F7449A4936C6518A6FD24A3C0984E9C09BF19395175F1BE2B5F`

This is according to [sha512 generator](https://passwordsgenerator.net/sha512-hash-generator/) I'm using.
What is the best way to do so on Oracle?

Thanks

Comment: First of all - do not store passwords as SHA2, use [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC). You can use Java based stored procedure/trigger to perform such a hashing, our you can found PLSQL encryption at github (not recommended). As well as host application can hash password before storing it into database.

Comment: Thanks Victor! This is not a password. I thought about Java, but I prefer to use Oracle if possible. I need this in order to simulate behavior of a system that uses this sha512.
I searched on google and found some hashing methods but I didn't succeed to adjust it to my case.

Comment: Java VM is a part of Oracle. You can write [Oracle Stored Procedure](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28843/tdddg_procedures.htm) using [PLSQL](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/plsql/index.html) or [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chfive.htm) or [C/C++](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/data_access.htm#CNCPT1759) programming languages.

Comment: @VictorGubin - There's no value in us rolling our own routines when Oracle has hashing functions built in.

Comment: [hashing ≠ encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4948322/1679849)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Oracle has built-in database support for SHA-512.

If you want a solution for pure SQL and your input string is within the SQL string length limit (4000 characters unless you've enabled the 12c extended varchar2 semantics) you can do this:

```
select standard_hash ( '230049008251111', 'SHA512')
from dual
/
```

If you have longer strings Oracle provides a package DBMS_CRYPTO (not to be confused with the deprecated DBMS_CRYPTO_TOOLKIT). You could use it like this ...

```
declare
     str clob;
     hsh raw(64);
begin      
     str := '230049008251111';
     hsh := dbms_crypto.hash (str, dbms_crypto.HASH_SH512);
     dbms_output.put_line(hsh);
end;
/
```

... or whatever makes sense for your application. There are three variants of `dbms_crypto.hash()` which take BLOB, CLOB and RAW. There is no variant for plain old varchar2. Not sure why. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_crypto.htm#ARPLS65670).

Both these calls produce the same output (as might be hoped):

```
DA9AA3ACDE64DB3297FF75FDE407DAF3DB7EFF0CDF987C6C16BAF28242997046997EBF5A2F6C4F7449A4936C6518A6FD24A3C0984E9C09BF19395175F1BE2B5F
```

---

As @WernfriedDomscheit observes, execute on DBMS_CRYPTO is not granted by default. However, `STANDARD_HASH()` is. So, depending on your requirements, you may need to engage with your DBA team to get the necessary privileges.

Comment: I tried to do so, but I got this: 
too many declarations of 'HASH' match this call

Comment: Just a note, by default the normal user has no execute privileges on `DBMS_CRYPTO` package. You may ask your DBA to grant it.

Comment: @shir - if this answer was helpful please consider accepting it. Accepted answers improve the quality of this site for future Seekers.